# onBackPressed() application is not closing

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onbackpressed

I have 3 activities
1st is login 
2nd is registration
3rd home activity (Bottom_nav) with bottom navigation and have 3 fragments A,B,C.

Login activity is launcher activity.

In login user is already login or not is checked
If user is not logged in it redirected to registration activity
Else to to home activity.

I have implemented onBackPressed() in home activity
But on double pressing back button activity get Paused and get resumed.

Here is my code:

```
 boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Bottom_nav.this.finish();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}




private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFrame, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFrame, new ProfileFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFrame, new NotificationFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_nav);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.MainFrame, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

}
```

This is log

```
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 2650
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 132340044
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), 
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=2650, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Bottom_nav, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4687850249260059972}]
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), 
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, 
firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Bottom_nav, 
firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-4687850249260059972, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterPhoneActivity, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4687850249260059974}]
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 132340054
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 184
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 132340135
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), 
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, 
firebase_previous_class(_pc)=RegisterPhoneActivity, 
firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-4687850249260059974, 
firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Bottom_nav, 
firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4687850249260059971}]
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 132340244
W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000000000002
Points are too far apart 4.000000000000002
W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000002058290173
Points are too far apart 4.000002058290173
W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000001624254724
W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000002923700373
Points are too far apart 4.000002923700373
W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.00000093640932
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

where am i going wrong? i didnt find any relevant ans to this

Comment: any error is showing or crashing app that moment?  if any crash then post correct log.

Comment: Is your code checking that the user is still logged in and restarting activity?

Comment: @farhana no app dosent crash

Comment: @Jantzilla im checking user is logged in or not at start of app but not in Home Activity

Comment: do you want to backtraced fragment?

Comment: @farhana i just want to exit app

Comment: i thing you are adding fragment to `Activity` rather than replace.when you pressed back button then it tries to back the fragment.

Comment: you need to change the way of changing fragment.

Comment: @farhana how? Can you explain?

Comment: you have two way, first is go back through with fragment if don't set `backstacktrace` then replace fragment rather than adding.

Comment: in homeactivity, try to use finishAffinity() in onBackPressed method.

Comment: @farhana for testing purpose i commented all fragment things and just kept activity related stuff still app is not exiting.

Comment: `if(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce){}` i think this condition is not working.

Comment: okay, I got it your launcher screen is `LoginActivity` when you pressed back then it goes to the login screen and your login condition is checked then 'LoginScreen` redirects you to`MainActivity` again

Comment: @farhana yes,  i said it in question my launcher activity is loginpage is their any way to kill that activity?

Comment: check updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you Launcher Screen is Login then use `finishAffinity()` method that will finish the current activity and all parent activities, but it works only in Android 4.1 or higher.

```
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Bottom_nav.this.finishAffinity();
    return;
}
```

If you don't want to backtraced in the fragment then use this.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

or you can change in your ways like

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFrame, new HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this.

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!doubleBackToExitPressedOnce){
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);


    }else {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

While opening a fragment you have to use this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFrame, new HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Not Working for me!

Comment: can you check how many times super.onBackPressed() is used @rishikesh_07?

Answer (score 0):

it might be more common to check for the state of the `SupportFragmentManager`'s backstack:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {

        /* only consider those clicks when there is no stack left */
    }
}
```

else your custom functionality will mess up the behavior of the `SupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: @HamedNabizadeh do you understand how the back-stack handles back clicks? finishing off an activity without confirmation is rather crappy and may produce undesired behavior.

Comment: @HamedNabizadeh just try both versions; instant exit on double-click is bad design. this might make sense with a single fragment, but not when having some more of them.

Comment: I upvoted, the user needs to change fragment transaction. when he pressed back then he needs to set  ` fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`  if he does not go through your code.

Answer (score 0):

What's actually happen on `Bottom_nav.this.finish();`? If it's not a finish activity statement, let's try it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce && (!isFinishing() || !isDestroyed())) {
        finish();
        //super.onBackPressed();
        Bottom_nav.this.finish();
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```